# Bootstrap submenu set width to 100 percent when the row is split into two columns

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, Jquery, JavaScript. In my page, I have a section which is split into two columns. First column(col-lg-8) has few fields. Second column(col-lg-4) has a Menu/SubMenu. I need to show the SubMenu in 100% width.

I referred few other previously asked questions, and the provided solutions worked perfectly fine when the first column is not present.

Here are few screenshots:
 [This is without First column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3lO7.jpg) where the submenu expanded to 100% width

After adding first column, It is expanded to 100% width but 100% only to the second column. I need it to be full screen width.

I am wondering if this (whatever I am trying to achieve) is even possible. Seeking experts advice. Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.This is my column1. Lets assume there are fields here already.</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Artist <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: static;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:5;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Here is link to my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/santto/yp2kts4k/

Comment: create that left side content with in nav and make that item alone float left, and nav float right

Comment: "After adding first column, It is expanded to 100% width but 100% only to the second column. I need it to be full screen width." - then where will first column content supposed to go

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9s1bk9Lf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/yp2kts4k/1/

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: relative;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:5;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">something is here already</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">Blackcat</div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Artist <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</div>
<!-- end navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top -->

<!-- container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Site content here...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End row -->
</div>
<!-- End container -->
```

Comment: Shiladitya - This approach seems to be working. I will try in my actual application. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: static;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:5;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
 
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">something is here already</div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">Blackcat</div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Artist <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</div>
<!-- end navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top -->

<!-- container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Site content here...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End row -->
</div>
<!-- End container -->
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9s1bk9Lf/)

make changes on this two lines

`<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">`  col-lg-4 to col-lg-12

`<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">something is here already</div>`

and moved this line inside `<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">`